# Shower/tub issue

Tags: plumbing, shower

We have heating and hot water from kitchen and bathroom sinks. When I turn on the shower or tub it runs hot for 30 seconds then cuts out completely. No water comes through. It only happens on the shower/tub.

Comment: Single handle faucet? Was any work done on the water main or in the homes pipes in the last few months? You may have a chunk of debris or buildup in the hot water line that is loose, and when the water starts flowing, it plugs the valve.You might want to turn off hot feed, pull the valve from the hot side, turn it back on deflecting water into the tub... run it for a minute.... then as long as water is still runing from hot, turn it back off and reassemble. Inspect the valve assembly while you have it apart

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we could help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Sounds like an anti scald faucet that is malfunctioning.

Comment: @EdBeal do they fail like this? (never owned one myself)

Comment: Yes , I have removed the cartridge on 1 brand another required the entire valve to be replaced, at that point I went to the old fashion 3 handle tub shower valve that did not have that feature.